# How to find $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} n^2 \Big[ \big(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\big)^{n+1}-\big(1+\frac{1}{n}\big)^{n}\Big]$?

Tags: limits

I would like to evaluate $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \Big(n^2 \Big[ \big(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\big)^{n+1}-\big(1+\frac{1}{n}\big)^{n}\Big]\Big)$.

Comment: Show us your work. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

We have
\begin{align*}
\left( {1 + \frac{1}{n}} \right)^n & = \exp \left( {n\log \left( {1 + \frac{1}{n}} \right)} \right) \\ &= \exp \left( {1 - \frac{1}{{2n}} + \frac{1}{{3n^2 }} + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{n^3 }}} \right)} \right) \\ & = e\left( {1 - \frac{1}{{2n}} + \frac{{11}}{{24n^2 }} + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{n^3 }}} \right)} \right)
\end{align*}
Also
\begin{align*}
\left( {1 + \frac{1}{{n + 1}}} \right)^{n + 1} & = e\left( {1 - \frac{1}{{2(n + 1)}} + \frac{{11}}{{24(n + 1)^2 }} + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{(n + 1)^3 }}} \right)} \right) \\ & = e\left( {1 - \frac{1}{{2n}} + \frac{{23}}{{24n^2 }} + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{n^3 }}} \right)} \right).
\end{align*}
With this, your sequence simplifies to
$$
en^2 \left( {\frac{1}{{2n^2 }} + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{n^3 }}} \right)} \right) = \frac{e}{2} + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{n}} \right).
$$
Thus, the limit is $e/2$.

Answer (score 0):

Say, that $f(x)=(1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}}$.

Now, we are asked to find $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} n²(y-x)(\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x})$. Where, $y=\frac{1}{n+1}, x=\frac{1}{n}$.

Now, $y-x=-\frac{1}{n²}$.

So, $\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}=\frac{\text{d} f(x)}{\text{d}x}|_{x=\frac{1}{n}}$.

So,  $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} n²(y-x)(\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x})$.

$=\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} n²(y-x)(\frac{\text{d} f(x)}{\text{d}x}|_{x=\frac{1}{n}})$.

$=\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} -(\frac{\text{d} f(x)}{\text{d}x}|_{x=\frac{1}{n}})$

$=\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} -((\frac{((1 + x)^{(1/x - 1)} (x - (1 + x) \text{ln}(1 + x)))}{x^2})_{x=\frac{1}{n}})$.

$=\lim \limits_{x \to 0} -((\frac{((1 + x)^{(1/x - 1)} (x - (1 + x) \text{ln}(1 + x)))}{x^2})$.

$=\lim \limits_{x \to 0} -e(\frac{(x - (1 + x)\text{ln}(1+x)}{x^2})$

(as $\lim \limits_{x \to 0} (1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}}$)

From L'Hospital rule

$=\lim \limits_{x \to 0} -e\frac{1-1-\text{ln}(1+x)}{2x}$

$=\lim \limits_{x \to 0} e\frac{\text{ln}(1+x)}{2x}=\frac{e}{2}$

$=\frac{e}{2}$